# Prevent scrolltop (to bottom) when scrollbar is clicked / in use

Tags: jquery

I'm making a little chat, just for fun

When new messages are loaded, it scrolls to the bottom of the div (#chatlist) that holds all messages. But it also tries to scroll down when I use the scrollbar of the div (overflow:auto).
How can I avoid this?

I have tried various no-click detection methods, without luck so far

Here is my code. An interval fires it every some seconds:

```
var chatlist = $('#chatlist');

function chatinterval() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/chatinterval.php',
        data: "dbtime=" + latestchat,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                chatlist.append(data.dbtext);
                latestchat = data.dblatest;
                // this part makes it scroll down
                chatlist.scrollTop(chatlist[0].scrollHeight - chatlist.height());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: oops sorry, it's actually a div with overflow: auto. So the "textarea" is #chatlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mousedown` and `scroll` events to control the flag variable (e.g. `clicked`). Since `mouseup` is not firing when you unclicking over scrollbar, we can set timeout (in my example 5 seconds) on every `scroll` event to wait until user stops scrolling manually. So the final code should look like this:

```
var chatlist = $('#chatlist');

var timer = null;
var clicked = false;

chatlist.on({
    mousedown: function() {
        clicked = true;
    },
    scroll: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            clicked = false;
        }, 5000);
    }
});

function chatinterval() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/chatinterval.php',
        data: "dbtime=" + latestchat,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                chatlist.append(data.dbtext);
                latestchat = data.dblatest;
                // this part makes it scroll down
                if (!clicked) {
                    chatlist.scrollTop(chatlist[0].scrollHeight - chatlist.height());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rkUt9/

Comment: There is a small flaw in your code, the way you made the demo, the user can't switch back to automated scrolling. He enters manual scrolling permanently. Could you throw a look at my answer and see if you can make a code implementation of my idea (if appropriate).

Comment: In my example you have to wait 5 seconds and auto scrolling returns back.

Comment: My apologies, but I'm sure the five second rule wasn't there when I opened it, I guess you added it slightly after or something didn't work quite well for me. This is a good snippet nonetheless, thank you.

Comment: This is an ok solution, but it does'nt work on mouse-scrollwheel action, and probably not on iPad etc. either. After some thinking I have made it so it only scrolls down if there are new messages. This is ok, perhaps mixed with your solution. Thank you

Comment: Anyway, guys, glad that you found something useful in this solution ;)

Comment: @mowgli For a flawless user experience, which you seem to be after, that is certainly not okay. Because in that case the user won't be able to see previous history if someone is actively writing. He'll try to go up, the script will send him down again - resulting annoyance. That's my opinion though, from a user point of view.

Comment: I appreciate your vision, VisioN ;)

Comment: @Peter Yes. I'm not looking for absolute flawless, just something that won't bother the user too much. Maybe I will allow user scrolling (without forced downscroll) and then add some kind of gentle message "xxxx wrote a new message! Scroll to bottom?" And when he/she clicks it scrolls down. That could work

Comment: That sounds even better, some small container that gently animates up from the bottom of the chat area. But animates so that it's bottom border touches the end of the text area. Meaning the animation will be only a few pixels above, enough to see the message and click it/touch it.

Comment: Found the issue with the above snippet @VisioN, it seems that after a while, when the messages become too many the script scrolls to some position in the middle, but not to the bottom. If you let it run for a while, you can replicate it. It's probably because of the container expanding. That was probably what confused me, because I had it running for a while.

Comment: @Peter It is because in DEMO `scrollTop` uses 100000 as an argument. It was just a DEMO :)

Comment: Well, still learning. So I thought there might be an error and I was eager to find it. Thanks again. I'll play with it a bit for educational purposes.